# Save Any Unsaved PFObject Even User Terminate the App

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am creating a social network app where user can create groups, post pictures, update pictures. etc

The problem I am experiencing is that sometimes, during the process of saving data to Parse, user can terminate the app.

I am wondering if there is any workaround this problem? Is there anyway I can get retrieve any Unsaved PFObjects and save them?

Comment: Why not save the data in your AppDelegate's `applicationWillTerminate`?

Comment: @pranav applicationWillTerminate only gives 5 seconds. While it might take longer than that since it is uploading data to Parse

Comment: In that case you might want to use `NSURLSession`. It will continue uploading in the background even if the system kills your app. However, if the user force quits your app it will be cancelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [saveEventually](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects-offline) good enough for you?

> The advantage is that if the user currently doesn't have a network connection, saveEventually will store the update on the device until a network connection is re-established. If your app is closed before the connection is back, Parse will try again the next time the app is opened.

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
gameScore[@"score"] = @1337;
gameScore[@"playerName"] = @"Sean Plott";
gameScore[@"cheatMode"] = @NO;
[gameScore saveEventually];
```

Or you can declare your app’s supported [background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), so when your app is not in foreground, you can still upload (or download) data.

Comment: I tried saveEventually before posting here. SaveEventually does not do the trick. I tried to upload a pfobject and i terminate it right away. SaveEventually did not help, it does not try again after the app relaunched @iforests

Comment: Would the backgroundtask work even if the user force trrminate the app?

Comment: No. That's not going to happen. Android can use a Service, but not iOS. And if saveEventually did not sync the data after the app relaunched, it might be a bug in Parse SDK or you just terminated the app too quickly.

Comment: Actually i've downloaded a couple of others app. And terminate it as soon as I update a profile picture. Just a fraction of a second. But when I relaunch the app, they still managed to reupload the picture. What might be the secret.

Comment: Well, what you need to do is save the new data locally, and try to sync the data with remote server when you have internet connection. I think that is exactly what saveEventually do, but if it's not going to work, maybe you can try to combine https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore  and save operator.

Comment: Thanks for being helpful